# Laravel actualizar status de registros

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postgresql

Buenas necesito actualizar automaticamente el status de mis presupuesto a "Vencido" cuando ya se haya pasado la Fecha de expiracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi tabla presupuesto:

```
id          
fecha_emision           
status          
total           
fecha_expiracion            
cod_usuario         
cod_cliente         
cod_contacto            
codigo_presupuesto          
nota            
respaldo            
descripcion         
validez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr eso necesitas configurar e utilizar el cron de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#introduction

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

A continuación creas un comando que va a realizar la actualización del estado:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ExpirarPresupuesto extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'presupuesto:expirar';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Marca los presupuestos como expirados cuando pasa dicha fecha';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // ...
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // *****agrega aquí el código que cambia el estado de los presupuestos expirados*****
    }
}
```

Por último agrega el comando a la configuración de los schedules:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#defining-schedules

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\ExpirarPresupuesto::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('presupuesto:expirar')
            ->dailyAt('04:00');
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo!!